# Android: Retrieve Zip code from phone

Tags: android, gps, zipcode

I have a very basic question. I want to retrieve a zip code automatically from the phone. I have been doing research and I've seen geocoder mentioned several times. But it seems overly complex for what I am trying to do and also that it returns a long/lat coordinate not a basic zip code.

My end game is basically to have a user press a button and the location will auto populate an edit text field or assign the value to a variable that I can use.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve a zip code automatically from the phone.

There is nothing in Android -- or any other mobile OS that I am aware of -- that supports this. For starters, nobody has to provide a physical address to their Android devices.

> I've seen geocoder mentioned several times. But it seems overly complex for what I am trying to do and also that it returns a long/lat coordinate not a basic zip code.

If you referring to [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), it returns a physical address given a latitude and longitude.